# Git writing objects hangs at 6%

Tags: git

My git is hanging at 6% of writting files to a remote repo.

Is there any git command that would let me know the file sizes that are about to be pushed? I am concerned that might be the reason is not letting me do the push.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out how big your repository is with:

```
git bundle create foo.bundle --all
du -sh foo.bundle
```

If you just think the culprit is a specific commit rather than the overall repository size (e.g. because you think a large binary might have accidentally slipped in somewhere), then you can identify large blobs with [this Perl script](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/Determine+the+Size+of+Each+Git+Commit).

Comment: Actually I just have one commit. I just created the repository. I would like to check the size of file by file, so I know which file is making my repo to not be able to push.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to push, you can't push the first 6%.

Looks like a MTU network problem to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

Comment: guettli I am not sure if I understand you correctly. How shall I try to appraoch this MTU problem? Is it because of large files?